# backBarButtonItem image right aligned, want centered

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I'm trying to set the backBarButtonItem to have a custom image:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:)))
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

I'm noticing that when I set the backBarButtonItem for my navigationController the image gets right aligned within the backBarButtonItem's frame:

[image]

[image]

What can I do to make the image centered, or even left aligned?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `backBarButtonItem` you need to set `leftBarButtonItem`

**Replace this**

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:)))
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

**by this**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:)))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: I will have to add this code to each "child" viewcontroller correct? I'd rather specify the back button for the entire nav stack in the "parent".

Comment: add this in your baseViewController in the viewDidLoad method, I had done this in several projects and work just fine

Comment: @ChrisAllinson let me know

Comment: I just tried setting the leftBarButtonItem in my "parent", then call self.navigationController?.pushViewController(...) and am finding the "child" to have nil as it's leftBarButtonItem :( ... also, the "parent" does have the arrow in the correct place, but I only want it to show on "child" pages as I want it to act as a back button.

Comment: Is it possible that my "child" has a different navigationController than my "parent"?

Comment: its possible, but I don't really underestand your viewControllers hierarchy can you post an image of what are your trying to do?

Comment: hmmmm, it does seem that my child is instantiated from a storyboard, and it does have it's own navController :S ... I suppose I'll have to set the leftBarButtonItem in each "child" ... thoughts? ... and thanks for your help :D

Comment: if your childs viewController have their own navigation controller anyway should work if your childs viewcontroller are subclassed from you baseViewController where you have implemented this @ChrisAllinson